# Prove that if N is a neighborhood of a, then a is in N.

Tags: general-topology

> Prove that if N is a neighborhood of a, then a is in N.

My text says it's trivial, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT: According to my text, $N\subset X$ is a neighborhood of $a \in$ X if $B(a;\delta)\subset N$.

And just in case, I'll define $B(a;\delta)$ :)

"Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. let $a\in X$ and $\delta>0$ be given. The subset of $X$ consisting of those points $x\in X$ such that $d(a,x)>\delta$ is called the open ball about a of radius $\delta$ and is denoted by $$B(a;\delta).$$

Sorry for all the confusion! I was unaware that there was more than one definition of a neighborhood.

But now that I think about it, since $\delta>0$ and $d(a,a)=0$, that means $d(a,a)>\delta$ is always true, so $a\in B\subseteq N$ is always true. That's it, right?

Comment: What definition of a neighborhood are you using where this isn't trivial?

Comment: What's your definition of a neighborhood?

Comment: How do you define "neighborhood" of $a$?  One definition is that a neighborhood includes an open set including $a$, in which case the transitivity of set inclusion is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

N is a neighborhood of a only if there is an open set O of N that contains a. That's why it's trivial that a is in N. (a $\in$ O $\subseteq$ N)